# unable to save json data to coredata

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I am new to iOS, i have created entity in core data with 
cityName 
distance 
driverId
strainDescription
strainId
strainImage 
strainName
strainTypeName 
vendorBusinessName 
vendorDriverEngagementId 
vendorOverallRating

of datatype NSstring, i am trying save the data in entity,expecting output

Below is my extracted JSON Object..

```
(
     {
    responseCode = 0;
},
    (
            {
        cityName = “mumbai”;
        distance = "2,412.3";
        driverId = 00000000076;
        strainDescription = "his is no creeper! ";
        strainId = 00000000004;
        strainImage = "www.d.net/dDocuments/StrainImages/Eyed Jamaican.jpg";
        strainName = "Eyed Jamaican";
        strainTypeName = "Body Car";
        vendorBusinessName = businessName11;
        vendorDriverEngagementId = 172;
        vendorOverallRating = "4.8";
    },
            {
        cityName = BLACKFOOT;
        distance = "2,412.3";
        driverId = 00000000073;
        strainDescription = "pain relief, anxiety";
        strainId = 00000000006;
        strainImage = "www.d.net/dDocuments/StrainImages/Abra Cadabra.jpg";
        strainName = "Abra Cada";
        strainTypeName = "Body C";
        vendorBusinessName = businessName15;
        vendorDriverEngagementId = 174;
        vendorOverallRating = "2.1";
    },
```

)
)

i am trying save the data in entity,expecting output

Core Data Entity

cityName distance driverId strainDescription strainId….

mumbai   2,412.3  00000000076 his is no creeper! 00000000004

BLACKFOOT 2,412.3  00000000073  pain relief  0006 …..

```
bd *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“db”inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
if (entity!=nil){
entity.cityName= [json valueForKey:@"cityName"];
entity.distance=[json valueForKey:@"distance"];
entity.distance=[json valueForKey:@“dr”iverID];
NSError *savingError = nil;
if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError]){                        
}else{
NSLog(@"Failed to save the context. Error = %@", savingError);
NSLog(@"Successfully saved the context.");
}
}else{
NSLog(@"Failed to create the doobsterdb");
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

json string and i want to save in core data entity

```
(
    {
    responseCode = 0;
},
    (
            {
        cityName = "mumbai";
        distance = "2,412.3";
        driverId = 00000000076;
        strainDescription = "his is no creeper!";
        strainId = 00000000002;
        strainImage = "www.dbst.net/DoobsterDocuments/StrainImages/Eyed Jamaican.jpg";
        strainName = "Eyed Jamaican";
        strainTypeName = "Body Car";
        vendorBusinessName = businessName11;
        vendorDriverEngagementId = 172;
        vendorOverallRating = "4.8";
    },
            {
        cityName = BLACKFOOT;
        distance = "2,412.3";
        driverId = 00000000076;
        strainDescription = "pain relief, anxiety";
        strainId = 00000000006;
        strainImage = "www.dbst.net/dbstDocuments/StrainImages/Abra Cadabra.jpg";
        strainName = "Abra Cadabra";
        strainTypeName = "Body Car";
        vendorBusinessName = businessName15;
        vendorDriverEngagementId = 174;
        vendorOverallRating = "2.1";
    },



   )
```

)